# Sp_Colums, Sp_procedures consuming resource

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am facing an issue of one of our production server which is in SQL Server 2008 R2 enterprise edition.

We are facing memory consumption on the server.

When I looked into SQL Server Profiler I found many session executing `sp_columns`, `sp_tables` and `sp_procedures` which are coming from a shell application.

Developers are not calling these system stored procedures from anywhere in the application. I am confused from where those stored procedures are getting called.

Can any one help please?

Comment: SSMS or some other DB management application is my guess. I doubt they would cause memory consumption problems though. You should be able to see application name column in Profiler.

Comment: Developers may not be calling sp_columns, sp_tables and sp_stored_procedures directly but a library that their code uses could be. e.g.: [jTDS](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/code/HEAD/tree/branches/jTDS%201.3%20(stable)/src/main/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/JtdsDatabaseMetaData.java) discovers schema information at run time by calling those three procs.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is: The system Stored Procedures where called from Crystal Report.

There is an option in Crystal report `verify on first refresh`, which is enabled by default to verify the database structure before executing reports, for keeping the mapping intact.

By just disabling this option, the System Stored Procedures stopped.